# Django login messages not being delivered as expected

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-messages

I'm building a Django project and I have a Django app for the login, which I called **members**. The project is behind the login, so all the URLs redirect to the login page if the user is not logged.

If the user inputs an existing user and password, the user can access to the site. This workd OK.

If the credentials are wrong, I want the app to send back a message to the user, something like *"Your credentials are wrong, try again"*, but I'm not getting this to work, even if I copied and pasted from the official documentation.

**My view:**

```
def login_user(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Credenciales inválidas.')
```

My **base template**, which other template extends:

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Mapa Primera Infancia: Login</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'login.css' %}" />
  </head>
  <body>

  <div class="msg">

    {% for message in messages %}
    <div class="alert alert-info">{{message}}</div>
{% endfor %}

  </div>

  {% block content %}
  {% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

**URLs** of the members app:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('login_user/', views.login_user, name='login'),
]
```

I don't know what is wrong and how to debug this. I suspect the problem is not in the template but in the response.

Any hints?

I'm working on Django 3.2.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, managed to get this done by myself. The error was that the templates in the members app were saved under templates/registration instead of templates/aunthenticate.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not redirecting to the login page to render the response.

```py
def login_user(request):
   username = request.POST['username']
   password = request.POST['password']
   user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
   if user is not None:
       login(request, user)
   else:
       messages.error(request, 'Credenciales inválidas.')
       return redirect(reverse('login')) 
'''if you have declared 'app_name = 'your_app_name', 
add this instead of that line: 
return redirect(reverse('your_app_name:login') ''''
```

Comment: Thanks, but that did not work either. I also tried ````return redirect('login')```` with no success.

Comment: Check if  'django.contrib.messages' is added in the list of INSTALLED_APPS in **settings.py**. If not, then add it. Check whether it works or not.

Comment: It's added. Also, the MIDDLEWARE, in the correct order. I also tried with different storage, with no result.

Comment: Sad to hear that. You might have checked the TEMPLATES[ ] in **settings.py** too. However, If you didn't, then check whether in the context_processor of TEMPLATES[], following line is added or not.                 'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

Comment: Indeed, I checked that and it's Ok. Thanks again for your comments. Let's see how this goes.